# Section won't appear when corresponding button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have five buttons. When one is clicked the active and active-btn classes are added to the button, the active class is also added to the corresponding section element that has the same id name as the button. CSS styling is supposed to change the screen background color for the particular section that the button corresponds to when the section element is active so its no longer displaying none, this isn't working for some reason. I don't know if its a styling issue or HTML or my JavaScript. I honestly don't know where I went wrong here. Please Help.

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
const sectBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.controls');
const sectBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.control');
const allSections = document.querySelector('.main-content');

function AtATime(parameter) {
  const track1 = document.querySelector('.home-icon');
  const track2 = document.querySelector('.about-icon');
  const track3 = document.querySelector('.portfolio-icon');
  const track4 = document.querySelector('.blogs-icon');
  const track5 = document.querySelector('.contact-icon');

  track1.classList.remove('active-btn');
  track2.classList.remove('active-btn');
  track3.classList.remove('active-btn');
  track4.classList.remove('active-btn');
  track5.classList.remove('active-btn');

  if (parameter === 'home') {
    track1.classList.add('active-btn');
  } else if (parameter === 'about') {
    track2.classList.add('active-btn');
  } else if (parameter === 'portfolio') {
    track3.classList.add('active-btn');
  } else if (parameter === 'blogs') {
    track4.classList.add('active-btn');
  } else if (parameter === 'contact') {
    track5.classList.add('active-btn');
  }

  allSections.addEventListener('click', (instance) => {
    const icon_id = instance.target.dataset.id;
    track1.classList.remove('active');
    track2.classList.remove('active');
    track3.classList.remove('active');
    track4.classList.remove('active');
    track5.classList.remove('active');
    if (icon_id) {
      //remove selected from other btns
      sectBtns.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.classList.remove('active')
      })
      instance.target.classList.add('active')

      //hide other sections
      sections.forEach((section) => {
        section.classList.remove('active')
      })

      const selector = `section.${icon_id}#${icon_id}`
      const icon_section = document.querySelector(selector);

      if (icon_section) {
        // Add the 'active' class to the element
        icon_section.classList.add('active');
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
}

:root {
  --color-primary: #191d2b;
  --color-secondary: #27AE60;
  --color-white: #FFFFFF;
  --color-black: #000;
  --color-grey0: #f8f8f8;
  --color-grey-1: #dbe1e8;
  --color-grey-2: #b2becd;
  --color-grey-3: #6c7983;
  --color-grey-4: #454e56;
  --color-grey-5: #2a2e35;
  --color-grey-6: #12181b;
  --br-sm-2: 14px;
  --box-shadow-1: 0 3px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

body {
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: var(--color-white);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
}

header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: var(--color-white);
  overflow: hidden;
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 3rem 18rem;
}

.section {
  transform: translateY(-100%) scale(0);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
}

.sec1 {
  display: none;
  transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  background-color: white;
}

.sec2 {
  display: none;
  transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  background-color: blue;
}

.sec3 {
  display: none;
  transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  background-color: gold;
}

.sec4 {
  display: none;
  transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  background-color: pink;
}

.sec5 {
  display: none;
  transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  background-color: red;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.section.sec5.contact.active {
  background-color: red;
}


/* Controls */

.controls {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 50%;
  right: 3%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  .active-btn {
    background-color: var(--color-secondary);
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    i {
      color: var(--color-white);
    }
  }
  .control {
    padding: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: var(--color-grey-4);
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow-1);
    i {
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      color: var(--color-grey-2);
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="look/look.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800&family=Roboto:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <title>Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body class="main-content">
  <header class="section sec1 header active" id="home">
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="section sec2 about" id="about"></section>
    <section class="section sec3 portfolio" id="portfolio"></section>
    <section class="section sec4 blogs" id="blogs"></section>
    <section class="section sec5 contact" id="contact"></section>
  </main>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="control control-1 active-btn home-icon" data-id="home" onclick="AtATime('home')">
      <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-2 about-icon" data-id="about" onclick="AtATime('about')">
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-3 portfolio-icon" data-id="portfolio" onclick="AtATime('portfolio')">
      <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-4 blogs-icon" data-id="blogs" onclick="AtATime('blogs')">
      <i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-5 contact-icon" data-id="contact" onclick="AtATime('contact')">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope-open"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="/utilities.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried using ChatGBT but the machine's solutions didn't work.

Comment: Don't waste time with ChatGPT, it doesn't know how to program any better than you do.

Comment: Don't add an event listener inside another event handler. Every time you click on one of the buttons, it adds another event listener to `.main-content`, but never removes the previous listener.

Comment: So how do I fix this, Im very new to programming in general (30 days-ish) and have been stumbling my way forward trying to complete this first project of mine. Do I split the stuff in the event listener into two event listeners, or do I do something else or what would a solution this my problem even look like?

Comment: I'm getting confused by your code. Both `AtATime()` and `AllSections.addEventListener()` seem to be implementing actions to run when you click on one of the buttons. Why do you have both of these?

Comment: One of them adds and removes the `active` class on the buttons, the other adds and removes `active-btn`. Isn't `active` supposed to be for the sections, not the buttons?

Comment: AtATime() is supposed to change the one of the buttons from its regular state to the active state changing the color from grey to green using the active-btn class. The AllSections.addEventListener() is supposed to leave all the other sections as display none, and apply the active class to the section that corresponds to its respective button to display the correct section in the browser. The reason I had active on both was because thats how it was done on the tutorial that I was following and it worked in the video but not when I tried.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need both the `AtATime()` function and the event listener, you can do everything in the event listener.

When you click on one of the buttons, `instance.target` will be the `<i>` element, not the `<div>` that contains it, so `instance.target.dataset.id` will not have the desired ID. Use `instance.target.closest(".control")` to find the `<div>` that contains it.

I've changed the event listener to be attached just to the `.controls` div rather than the entire body.

You were adding both `active` and `active-btn` to the buttons. They only need `active-btn`. Also, your `.forEach()` was looping over `.controls` rather than all the `.control` divs. And the `.active-btn` class should be added to the div, not `instance.target`.

In the CSS you need to use the selector `.control.active-btn`, so that this will take precedence over `.control`.

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
const sectBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.control');
const allSections = document.querySelector('.controls');

allSections.addEventListener('click', (instance) => {
  const control = instance.target.closest('.control');
  const icon_id = control?.dataset?.id;
  if (icon_id) {
    //remove selected from other btns
    sectBtns.forEach((btn) => {
      btn.classList.remove('active-btn')
    })
    control.classList.add('active-btn')

    //hide other sections
    sections.forEach((section) => {
      section.classList.remove('active')
    })

    const selector = `section.${icon_id}#${icon_id}`
    const icon_section = document.querySelector(selector);

    if (icon_section) {
      // Add the 'active' class to the element
      icon_section.classList.add('active');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
}

:root {
  --color-primary: #191d2b;
  --color-secondary: #27AE60;
  --color-white: #FFFFFF;
  --color-black: #000;
  --color-grey0: #f8f8f8;
  --color-grey-1: #dbe1e8;
  --color-grey-2: #b2becd;
  --color-grey-3: #6c7983;
  --color-grey-4: #454e56;
  --color-grey-5: #2a2e35;
  --color-grey-6: #12181b;
  --br-sm-2: 14px;
  --box-shadow-1: 0 3px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

body {
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: var(--color-white);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
}

header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: var(--color-white);
  overflow: hidden;
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 3rem 18rem;
}

.section {
  transform: translateY(-100%) scale(0);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
}

.sec1 {
  display: none;
  transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  background-color: white;
}

.sec2 {
  display: none;
  transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  background-color: blue;
}

.sec3 {
  display: none;
  transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  background-color: gold;
}

.sec4 {
  display: none;
  transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  background-color: pink;
}

.sec5 {
  display: none;
  transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  background-color: red;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.section.sec5.contact.active {
  background-color: red;
}


/* Controls */

.controls {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 50%;
  right: 3%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  .control.active-btn {
    background-color: var(--color-secondary);
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    i {
      color: var(--color-white);
    }
  }
  .control {
    padding: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: var(--color-grey-4);
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow-1);
    i {
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      color: var(--color-grey-2);
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="look/look.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800&family=Roboto:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <title>Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body class="main-content">
  <header class="section sec1 header active" id="home">
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="section sec2 about" id="about"></section>
    <section class="section sec3 portfolio" id="portfolio"></section>
    <section class="section sec4 blogs" id="blogs"></section>
    <section class="section sec5 contact" id="contact"></section>
  </main>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="control control-1 active-btn home-icon" data-id="home">
      <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-2 about-icon" data-id="about">
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-3 portfolio-icon" data-id="portfolio">
      <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-4 blogs-icon" data-id="blogs">
      <i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-5 contact-icon" data-id="contact">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope-open"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="/utilities.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I just ran your code in VScode and it didn't work. The classes of 'active' and 'active-btn' were toggled when the buttons were clicked, but the screen color remained the same. I did the demo snippet in stackoverflow and is seems to work but when I copied it line into my editor it didn't work. I don't know whats going on at this point. Im questioning my life, my will to live and now I wanna go kick something.

Comment: I don't use VSCode so I don't know why it doesn't run there. If it works in a browser, that's what matters.